# How to open a Bootstrap modal without jQuery or bootstrap.js javascript?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a VERY LIGHT survey application. This application runs in third world countries in locations with very limited connection.

We found that the loading-time is proportional to user Engagement (Very important to us).

Today I'm using 2 libs - VueJS and a custom bootstrap build. I would like to invoke a modal. But the modal requires to add the Bootstrap Javascript and the jQuery. those libs almost doubles the loading time.

How can I open a modal without adding those two libs?

Comment: a hacky way would be to simply copy-paste the boostrap modal jquery plug in into your javascript and call it without jquery nor bootstrap javascript (of course you would emulate in vanilla js all the jquery stuff needed by the modal, but it is doable ina few lines of javascript)

Comment: Modals are simply fullscreen DIV's (position: fixed), with a z-index higher than the current page.  You can also apply some trasparancy to this DIV to give a more pleasing view.

Comment: https://codepen.io/timothylong/pen/HhAer/
check this one. its a css model.. no need any kind of js. I hope it'll help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@uday's  link to CSS only modal is a nice trick, but might be awkward to use if you use #tag's for other purposes (eg, Routing & param passing).

So here is an example that uses very little JS to achieve something very similar.  I've tried to keep the Snippet as small as possible so that it's easy to see what's happening.

```js
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var container = modal.querySelector(".container");

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  modal.classList.remove("hidden")
});

document.querySelector(".modal").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target !== modal && e.target !== container) return;     
  modal.classList.add("hidden");
});
```

```css
.modal {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Transparent dimmed overlay */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.modal.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.modal .container {
 display: table-cell;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 200px;
}

.modal .body {
  box-shadow: 5px 10px #888888;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>Show Modal</button>

<div class="modal hidden">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="body">
      <p>Click outside this box to close the modal.<p>
      <p>You could of course add a close button etc</p>
      <p>But this is left for the OP todo</p> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

You don't need any css style. You should create the bootstrap modal in your HTML, then in your js, you have to simply give it some style according to the following description:

```
var locModal = document.getElementById('locModal');
var btnclose = document.getElementById('w-change-close');
var btnShow= document.getElementById('w-change-location');


//show the modal
btnShow.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    locModal.style.display = "block";
    locModal.style.paddingRight = "17px";
    locModal.className="modal fade show"; 
});
    //hide the modal
    btnclose.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        locModal.style.display = "none";
        locModal.className="modal fade";
});
```

---

The  HTML should be like this:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button id="w-change-location" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#locModal">
                Change Location
   </button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="locModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="locModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="locModalLabel">Choose Location</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" id="w-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="city"> City</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="state"> State </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="w-change-close" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="w-change-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

We write private code for our modal.

```
let modal = document.getElementById('our-modal');
let modalContentElm = modal.querySelector('.modal-content');
let allModalButtons = modal.querySelectorAll('.modal-footer > .btn');
let outerClick = true;

let openStyle = () => { //MODAL SHOW
    modal.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(() => { modal.style.opacity = 1; }); //FOR TRANSITION 
};
let closeStyle = () => { //MODAL HIDE
    modal.style.display = 'none';
    modal.style.opacity = 0;
};

//NO CLOSE MODAL WHEN YOU CLICK INSIDE MODAL
modalContentElm.onclick = () => {
    outerClick = false;
};

//CLOSE MODAL WHEN YOU CLICK OUTSIDE MODAL
modal.onclick = () => {
    if(outerClick){ closeStyle(); }
    outerClick = true;
};


for(let btn of allModalButtons){
    btn.onclick = () => {

        closeStyle();

        if(btn.getAttribute('id') === 'success-btn'){
            //PLEASE WRITE 'success-btn' IN THE ID VALUE OF THE CONFIRM BUTTON
            console.log('Click Yes');
        }
        else{
            console.log('Click Cancel');
        }
        //..... more else if or else for more modal buttons

    };
}
```

Whenever we want to open modal

```
openStyle();
```

Whenever we want to close modal on manuel

```
closeStyle();
```

**It's a bit laborious, but it works. A more general class can be written.**

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **bootstrap 5**, you can easily show and hide modal with js:

[Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#methods)

```
const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal')); // creating modal object
myModal.show(); // show modal
myModal.hide(); // hide modal
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to use Bootstrap for Modal CSS, this is what their Javascript renders. You simply need to use your own Javascript to toggle it (no animation obviously):

```js
const diag = document.querySelector(".modal-container");

document.querySelector(".btn-close").addEventListener("click", () => {
  diag.classList.add("d-none");
});

document.querySelector(".btn-show").addEventListener("click", () => {
  diag.classList.remove("d-none");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn-show btn btn-primary">Show Dialog</button>

<div class="modal-container d-none">
  <div class="modal-backdrop show"></div>
  <div class="modal show d-block" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">
                      Dialog Title
                  </h5>
                  <button class="btn-close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body text-center">
                  Dialog Content
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- `.modal-backdrop` is for the black backdrop behind the dialog.
- The `div` with `.modal` needs `d-block` or else it would not show up (its CSS `display: none`) even with `.show`. The Javascript sets an inline `display: block` to it so we have to override it with `d-block` as well.
- You need `.show` for both the `.modal-backdrop` and `.modal`.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the modal using a button. you can add the bootstrap options to that button `data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalTarget"` and also a onclick function like `onclick="whenOpenModal();"`

```
function whenOpenModal(){
   console.log("modal opened");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try Laravel 9 and Bootstrap 5 without a jQuery  for using Modal Bootstrap.

I doing delete the data:
my modal id is = `deleteModal`.

- 1- add `wire:ignore.self` in Div modal for open and stay open modal.
- 2- at the end of function to deleted data insert

  `$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('closeModal');`

  that means call Event `"closeModal"` .
- 3- add `@stack('script')` for listening to script.
- 4- add

```
@push('script')
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('closeModal', event => {
            document.querySelector('#deleteModal').style.display = "none";
            document.querySelector('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        })
    </script>
@endpush
```

for close modal.

the div by class "modal-backdrop" at the end of html page that is dark at the background the Modal.