# How to open Boostrap 3 modal box from Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have tried to open the Modal box like this.

```
window.getElementById("modal-box-click-counter").showModal();
```

and

```
var modal = document.getElementById("modal-box-click-counter");
      modal.modal("show");
```

This is the whole script I am trying to get to work:

```
function clickCounter() {
  var clicks;

  function loadClicks() {
    clicks = sessionStorage.getItem("clickcount");
  }

  function setClicks() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("clickcount", clicks);
  }

  function init() {
    loadClicks();

    if (clicks >= 4) {
      console.log("WORKING " + clicks);

      // I WANT THIS TO WORK.
      $("#modal-box-click-counter").modal("show");

    } else {
      clicks++;
      setClicks();
      console.log(clicks);
    }
  }

  if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
    window.addEventListener("click", init);
  } else {
    console.log("Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...");
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", clickCounter);
```

But I can't get it to work. I have JQuery and Bootstrap loaded in the right order in functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no egde cases you can simply work with the official bootstrap example: [Modal Live Demo 3.4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#live-demo)

Comment: Yes I am, but there is no Vanilla Javascript there on that link, only JQuery.

Comment: Ok, maybe this answer could help you: [How to open a Bootstrap modal without jQuery or bootstrap.js javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53594423/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-without-jquery-or-bootstrap-js-javascript)