# Open a modal made with bootstrap without JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want it to show me a modal after making an AJAX request if there is an error. This has to be without JQuery, with pure JavaScript code, is there a way? By the way, I'm using bootstrap 4. Thanks

How to open a modal with Bootstrap without Jquery

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53594423/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-without-jquery-or-bootstrap-js-javascript

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)